# how to add label to matrices multiplication

Tags: equations

in the below latex code, i am displaying two matrices multiplied by each other and the result of the multiplication

to add a label to the code posted below , i tried to include the below code inside \begin{equation} and \end{equation} and add\label but when i compile the code i recive errors

how can i add label to the below code

**code**

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/k}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ -v
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

**what i tried is**

```
\begin{equation}

\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/k}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
 =
\begin{bmatrix}
 u \\ -v
\end{bmatrix}

\end{equation}
```

Comment: You should either use `\[` and `\]` or the `equation` environment, not both nested inside one another. If that doesn't help, please add a minimum working example (MWE).

Comment: @wrtlprnft please have a another look, i updated the question with a sample code i tried

Comment: by using the `equation` environment, you will get an equation number.  but blank lines are not permitted within a math environment.  remove the blank lines, or put a `%` at the beginning of those lines if you want a visual space in the input file.

Comment: You can't have blank lines in an `equation`. Just get rid of the first and last line and everything is tickety-boo.

Comment: Yous can use \tag{} or \tag*{} if you want something other than an equation number.